# NSTimer not working in Notification (Xcode6)

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstimer

In my recorder app I have a timer declared in .h and started in the startRecord-function:

```
         AufnahmeTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                    target:self
                                                  selector:@selector(AufnahmeTimerFunktion:)
                                                  userInfo:nil
                                                   repeats:YES];
```

AufnahmeTimerFunktion just writes an NSLog at the moment. 
[image]

(sorry, I am not able to insert code containing curly brackets, therefore the screenshots)
This works fine. In the RecordingAktion notification sent by the the AVRecorder the timer is invalidated as expected.
But I want to start the timer when the AVRecorder sends his notification that recording has started. The notification action is called, but the timer with the exact same code does not start.

[image]

I have no idea what is going wrong here. I used timers in many applications since Xcode 3.

Comment: So you are talking about [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/AVRecorder/Introduction/Intro.html) class?

Comment: case 1: NSLog printing on console ?

Comment: try adding it to currentRunLoop like 
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:AufnahmeTImer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

Comment: I did that already with no success